# jQuery looping restart when variable reaches limit

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function, that every 6,5 secs executes a `slideHighs` function:

```
 initialId=1;

   function autoSlider(){
      setInterval(function() {
         autoId=initialId++;
         slideHighs(autoId);
      }, 6500);
   }
```

I am not able to solve 2 problems:

- When loading page, I need this function to start executing the first
  loop (with `autoId val = 1`) without waiting for the 6,500 ms to
  start, then increase to 2,3 etc... each 6,500 ms. I mean, avoid first 6,500 interval.
- Variable limit is 4, when it is reached, value must restart to 1.

Comment: **solution problem 1**: as first line of the function put `slideHighs(1);` (before the `setInterval`) ...I'm afraid that's the only way to solve that

Comment: Already solved, used also your proposal. Thank you for your attention

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You can call same code which is inside `setInterval` first with `initialId = 1` and then inside `setInterval` check if `initialId` value and reset it.

```
var initialId = 1;

//call function outside interval first
autoId=initialId;
slideHighs(autoId);

function autoSlider(){
      setInterval(function() {
         autoId=initialId++;
         slideHighs(autoId);
         //reset variable
         if(initialId>4)
           initialId =0;
      }, 6500);
   }
```

Comment: This was first valid reply, problem solved. Very grateful. Ill tick in 6 minutes

Comment: @ downvoter, please be careful while making votes. This is not fun site.

Comment: I would put those two lines that are now outside the function (`autoId=initialId;` and `slideHighs(autoId);`) better **inside the function**, just **outside the interval**. It doesn't change functionality, but is so much cleaner and more Object-Oriented. Use as less global vars as possible in JS

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
initialId = 0;

function autoSlider(){
    // use var keyword to prevent declaring the variable on the global namespace
    var autoId = initialId++;
    slideHighs(autoId);
    if ( initialId == 4 ) {
        initialId = 1;
    }
}
```

To call `autoSlider()` when loading the page, you do this:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    autoSlider();
    setInterval(autoSlider, 6500);
});
```

Or, use the shortcut method for $(document).ready(), like this:

```
$(function() { 
    autoSlider();
    setInterval(autoSlider, 6500);
});
```

Comment: No idea where the downvotes are coming from. I stand by my answer.

Comment: already solved Charlie, thank you for your attention. dont know whats up with downvotes.

Comment: I downvoted this one, not the others, because you are calling `setInterval` inside itself, so you will get exponentially more threads

Comment: Yep. I deserved that downvote. I was seeing that as setTimeout, not setInterval. My mistake.

Comment: ok looking good now, and it wont kill your browser :) - downvote removed

Answer (score 1):

```
initialId = 1;

(function(){  //this will solve first problem
  slideHighs(initialId);
})();


function autoSlider(){
   setInterval(function() {
      if(initialId == 4) initialId =1;  //2nd resolve
      autoId=initialId++;
      slideHighs(autoId);
   }, 6500);
}
```

Comment: already solved Aaron, than you for your attention. dont know whats up with downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an anonymous function. Give it a name and use it on dom ready and in your interval :

```
var initialId = 0; //0 so it prevent the first call to be `2`.

function doSomething() {
     var autoId=initialId++;
     slideHighs(autoId);
}

$(doSomething);//Dom ready shortcut

setInterval(doSomething, 6500);
```

As for your second question, just use a condition :

```
function doSomething() {
     initialId++;
     if(initialId > 4) initialId = 1;
     var autoId=initialId;

     slideHighs(autoId);
}
```

Note : `autoId` is pretty useless...